# How to send new request with object instead of bytes?

Tags: go

I need to send an object of data e.g. `{hello: "world", goodbye: "world"}` to an API. I'm doing it like this right now:

```
inputs := form.GetElementsByTagName("input")

var data = make(map[string]interface{}) // after adding values this looks like this: {hello: "world", goodbye: "world"}

for value := range inputs {
    // Append all values from the inputs to a new array, with the key named by the input name attribute
    if inputs[value] != nil && inputs[value].(*dom.HTMLInputElement).Value != "" {
        data[inputs[value].(*dom.HTMLInputElement).Name] = inputs[value].(*dom.HTMLInputElement).Value
    }
}

parsedData, _ := json.Marshal(data)
req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewBuffer(parsedData))

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

client := &http.Client{}
go func() { // Must be a goroutine
    response, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer response.Body.Close()
}()
```

The problem I'm having is since we're sending it as a byte, the server always returns error responses as it's expecting to deal with an object.

How can I make sure it's sending an object instead of bytes?

Comment: What do you mean, "an object"? Do you mean JSON?

Comment: Yes, I mean a JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while you are sending the data in json format, so change your content-type when setting the request headers, along with that do not skip the error to check what is the error returned:

```
parsedData, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
}
req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, parsedData) // send the parseData which are bytes returned from the marshal.
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json") // set the content type to json

go func() { // Must be a goroutine
    response, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
}()

// you should check for response status to verify the details as
fmt.Println("response Status:", response.Status)
fmt.Println("response Headers:", response.Header)
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
```

One thing that should be taken into consideration is that you have not exported your struct fields. That can be the reason your json string becomes empty. Make your struct fields exportable by making their first letter of each field in caps.

Comment: There are no errors returned by those functions. What I meant is that the API response returns error responses such as "field X is required". Changing the content-type to json also have no effect, both of them works normally (through e.g. Postman)

Comment: @JeffreyAnderson but chaneg the content type since you are sending the json object in bytes. Also you are skipping the errors try to print them like I did and then run the code again see what it prints and psot in your question. It will be of help

Comment: I did run the error checks and I did change the content type. As I said, no errors are printed.

Comment: @JeffreyAnderson also if they are saying that `field x is required` then you need to be specific that which field has validation since you are sending the request to the server. It is for sure that there are validations on the server.

Comment: It is saying that `field x is required` because when I debug the given parameters to the server, neither of the fields are present. The interface should hold e.g. `&v%!(EXTRA *mystruct.Mystruct=&{0 hello world })` but instead, as I'm sending bytes, it holds `&v%!(EXTRA *mystruct.Mystruct=&{0      })`, for clarification, the API checks for `req.FormValue()` to get values.

Comment: @JeffreyAnderson why you are using `bytes.NewBuffer` since the parsseData returned from the marshal is itself in bytes so you can send them directly check my updated code also print the data as `fmt.Println(string(parseData))` to see if it contains the data.

Comment: It contains the data. I cannot pass `parsedData` to the request: `cannot use parsedData (variable of type []byte) as io.Reader value in argument to http.NewRequest: missing method Read
`

Comment: @JeffreyAnderson yes I get it you need to implement io.reader for which you have used `bytes.NewBuffer`. Try to check the status of the response along with that the body of the response. Also since you have said that due to sending bytes your data is changed that is not possible. Since you are just converting your struct to json. So you should check you data before sending.

Comment: The body is empty (unless I decode it like so `json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&j)`, then it returns the error messages about field X being empty etc) and the status is 400 (as expected, that is what the API returns when a field is missing)

Comment: @JeffreyAnderson you are going right now all you have to do is check for which field is empty and why it is going empty. So try to check you data before sending and if you have problem regarding creating the buffer then flush the buffer before sending to check if it contains the data.

Comment: No field in the data that being sent is empty. I'm sending bytes when it expects an object, content-type does not change that. I printed the entire request that the API receieves, and nothing there is present because bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the `"net/url"` package.

```
data := url.Values{}

for value := range inputs {
    // Append all values from the inputs to a new array, with the key named by the input name attribute
    if inputs[value] != nil && inputs[value].(*dom.HTMLInputElement).Value != "" {
        data.Add(inputs[value].(*dom.HTMLInputElement).Name, inputs[value].(*dom.HTMLInputElement).Value)
    }
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, actionUrl, strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```